# Em SEO usar mais de um link no HTML para outra página é ruim?

Tags: html, seo

É uma má prática de SEO usar mais de uma tag `a` em uma estrutura HTML para outra página HTML sendo o `href` o mesmo link?

Ex:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <a href='link1.html'><img src='path/img.jpg'/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2><a href='link1.html'>TITULO DO LINK AQUI</a></h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href='link1.html'>Descrição sobre o link vem aqui, lorem ipsum....</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aparentemente vc pode usar quantos links repetidos quiser apontando para o mesmo destino. O Google não é claro, e nunca foi, com as suas regras de PageRank. Inclusive eles vivem mudando essas regras, então a única forma de ter certeza é fazendo testes e monitorando os resultados.

O mais provável no entanto é que o Google separa do documento todos os links e faz uma amostragem. Ao que parece ele pode ignorar os links repetidos, considerando apenas o primeiro. No caso de ancoras diferentes, mas apontando para o mesmo URL, pode ser que ele considere o link 2x, mas não é possível afirmar isso...

> ... *"se você tiver dois links para a mesma página de uma página específica, mas o texto âncora no primeiro for diferente do anterior, o Google em 2009 teria usado o texto âncora do primeiro link."*

Aqui tem dois artigos que vão te ajudar a entender melhor

https://searchengineland.com/googles-matt-cutts-one-page-two-links-page-counted-first-link-192718

https://searchenginewatch.com/sew/news/2347404/two-links-different-anchor-text-same-url-does-it-matter-to-google

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento e pelas referências.

Comment: @EliseuB. Tudo referente aos métodos do google são meio obscuros, mas esse tipo de coisa não costuma receber punição ate onde sei, depois estude sobre nofolow pode te interessar caso realmente queira que o google ignore algum link, mesmo assim nada garante isso...

Comment: obrigado, sempre uso ref de a, vou manter os links e ver como ficará a taxa de rejeição.